# C# - retrieve extended file properties from shell32?

Tags: c#, listview

I'm trying to retrieve extended file properties in Listview, but I'm geting "**object reference not set to an instance of object**" error in shell32.Namespace path argument, although It's definitely not empty string. Here is my code:

```
using Shell32;

namespace MyApp.FileManager
{
    public static class FileManager_Methods
    {
        public static Shell shell= new Shell();
        public static Folder folder_prop;
        public static FolderItem prop;

        public static void ShowDirectory(ListView Lview, string Path)
        {

            //error here
            folder_prop = shell.NameSpace(Path);

            Lview.Items.Clear();

           //code for displaying items in listview...

        }
    }
}
```

Reference to Shell Controls and Automation is added, and same code works fine for me in VB.NET. What am I doing wrong here, something else missing for C# ?

Comment: you havent initialized shell

Comment: @BugFinder your nickname fits the situation perfectly

Comment: ok thanks for response, but how do I initialize It ?

Comment: You should stick with vb if you have working code and dont know how to do "shell = new Shell();"  you will be on a long pointless journey

Comment: ok, bugFinder thanks for downvote, but before you post anything that you're sure about BE sure that you are right. THAT doesn't work and It produces another much bigger error, I know what you meant by that. And this is why I asked in first place. My question is edited also.

Comment: Firstly thanks for assuming that was me.. second - your question is vauge - but my point is still valid - if it works in VB leave it in VB

Comment: PS it works fine in win7

Comment: ok, sorry, except my apology please. But I can't do that, I'm having an assignment to translate whole project into C#.

Comment: and the error I'm getting about inicialization is: An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. Win 7 also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. error was in  folder_prop = shell.NameSpace(Path);. I should use this code inside loop where I enumerate directory.